# I need help calling new data from a Google Form sheet into multiple other sheets automatically

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So, I'm setting up something for a friend of mine, and I've been trying to mess around in Google Sheets with getting something to work, but I've run into a bit of a roadblock. To put it simply, I want data from a google form to go to a sheet, and for every new line added to that sheet from the form to automatically update other sheets by adding a new column with that data into them.

[image: Image of Form->Sheet]

So every single time a new form post is completed and a new row is made above, I want every single time a new line is added to make a new column in here with that data:

Want it to make a new column next to the last one here and input the info from the form into said new column

[image: Want it to make a new column next to the last one here and input the info from the form into said new column.]

I know this is probably possible with coding it right or with scripts and triggers, but I don't really know how to do that, and I was directed to ask here as my best bet. If anything I've said is unclear, I can try to clear some of it up more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was already posted on Web Applications [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/134693/88163). Cross-posting across [se] sites isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this formula into Sheet2 in first column:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FormResponses!B1:B)
```

this should do what you request

if you want to have only unique values add `UNIQUE`

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FormResponses!B1:B))
```

Comment: Scratch the previous comment, there is still one thing I need to know, which is how can I make the info being transposed over make a new column on the sheet of the second image?

Comment: not sure I understand you... can you explain in more datail, perhaps share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Yeah, I was a little confusing about it, sorry.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VnYO3jZU_8gwF4tdF7eroKHGvQbfMNvcsohhlQsrwpo/edit?usp=sharing

Explaining it in detail, I'm setting up a sheet that will take information from multiple other user's sheets and paste it together into one big masterlist so people dont have to look at each individual user's sheet for said information. The user's sheets are based off a separate google sheet that is copied and modified to fit their character's information.

Comment: Im more or less trying to figure out how to set up a google form that, when filled out, will send that character name to every copied document, add a new column with their name, and then send that information back to the masterlist in sheet2 to be set up in the way shown. The main issue I've run into is how to make it so that a new column with the form info is added every time a new form post is made, I dont know how to make it add that new column with the form info. My best guess is to input something on the separate sheet file users copy for their character info to do it, but I dont know.

Comment: delete everything in Sheet2 and paste this in A1: `=TRANSPOSE('Sheet1(LINESKIP)'!A1:L)` ( - is that what you are after?)

Comment: Not quite, so in "Form Responses 1", I want any new info coming into that form to automatically be sent into this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wm750iuy0T4vP0x5nG15F0KN2SqGRXhr3S9bHT5Pn_4/edit?usp=sharing 

as a new column past column M. And then I want that new info to be sent back to the masterlist sheet with the link of the original sheet to be displayed in 'Sheet2' of the masterlist.

Because more and more users will come, I need something that will repeatedly add new columns and new entries into both the user sheet and the masterlist based on new form entries.

Comment: in N2 you will need: `=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("1VnYO3jZU_8gwF4tdF7eroKHGvQbfMNvcsohhlQsrwpo", "Form Responses 1!B3:B"))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOnoW.png so when you enter new name in for it will be added there and a new column will be created also

Comment: Oh, that actually worked! I was worried I had to do something a lot more complex, thank you!